# python -v print messy text is this normal?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I type `python -v` I got this. Coming from a node.js dev this is strange to me.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Does the python -v Command Do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43970012/what-does-the-python-v-command-do)

Comment: For Python and many other applications, ``-v`` means verbose. Why are you confused by seeing verbose output in verbose mode? Why do you use verbose mode when you don't want to see verbose output? What behaviour did you expect instead?

Answer (score 1):

`-v` flag in python refers to **verbose**. It is printing every import that python is using internally. The output is completely normal.

Python [command-line documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html) describes the -v flag as:

> Print a message each time a module is initialized, showing the place (filename or built-in module) from which it is loaded. When given twice (-vv), print a message for each file that is checked for when searching for a module. Also provides information on module cleanup at exit.

If you instead intend to print **python version**, you can use `python -V` (with a capital V) or `python --version`.

Comment: This answer succinctly explains the difference between `-v` and `-V`. Nicely done.